# Android Speech Recognition Test Connection?

Tags: android, connection, voice-recognition

Is there a way to test a devices' connection to the Speech recognition servers before I initiate listening? Is it as simple as testing the internet connection? Like so :

```
public boolean isOnline() 
{
   ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(cm == null || cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null || !cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
    return false;

   return true;
}
```

Or do you have to test the internet connection AND specifically a connection to the speech servers?